# Como inserir um valor filtrado por SELECT dentro de uma query UPDATE no script PHP

Tags: php, script

Eu só preciso pegar o R.A do `SELECT` e jogar no `UPDATE`, porém toda vez que coloco `$usuario['ra]`, da um erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\myschool\teste.php on line 36

```
<?php

require_once('db_class.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE ativo_sn = 'n' ";

$objdb = new db();
$link = $objdb->conecta_mysql();
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
?>

     if($result){
      $dados = array();
      while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
         $dados[] = $linha;
      }

       foreach ($dados as $usuario) {
       ?>
         <label><?php echo $usuario['nome_user'];?> </label><br/>
         <label><?php echo $usuario['ra'];?> <br/>
         <a href="" onclick="<?php mysqli_query($link,
            "UPDATE usuario SET ativo_sn = 's' WHERE ra = '**PRECISO COLOCAR R.A AQUI**' ");
            ?>">Aceitar</a><hr/>
            <?php

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Altera a sua query para

```
mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE usuario SET ativo_sn = 's' WHERE ra = '".$usuario['ra']."' ");
```

Você precisa tirar das aspas variavel que vc quer passar.

Comment: deu certo !! porem toda vez que entro na pagina ele ja executa a query, mesmo quando coloquei no onclick do link, troquei por button e mesmo assim vai automatico :\ aa

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, acho que seria possível otimizar o código também populando os labels e os hyperlinks dentro do próprio while, dispensando a criação do array $dados e do foreach.

```
while(....) {
     $usuario = $dados['nome_user'];
     $ra = $dados['ra'];
     ....
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, Paulo !!